# logout script to restore "clean" user environment with 18.04 Desktop?

Tags: scripts, 18.04, logout, gnome-session, education

I'm configuring a bunch of laptops for a teaching lab, running 18.04 Desktop. They have an admin account and a standard account for students. I would like the student account to behave as much like the Mac OS Guest account as possible, so that at GUI logout, the entire user home is wiped and replaced with a fresh one from /etc/skel .
I did this successfully a few versions ago, but that was with lightppd. How do logout scripts work with gnome-shell?

Comment: You will find the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/85985/how-can-i-make-a-script-run-automatically-after-gdm-login-and-logout

Comment: ah OK, looks like in 18.04 the relevant directory is /etc/gdm3 (formerly known as /etc/gdm)